# Show birthdays happening within a week, using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database of users with birthdays, would it be possible to display whose birthday it is today and any birthdays coming up within a week of the current date. I have this but it's not working.

```
<?php
  $retrieveBirthday = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM memberData WHERE mBirthday BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK" );
    echo $retrieveBirthday;
?>
```

Where am I going wrong here? I know it should be mysqli but security isn't an issue here.

Comment: I can tell you're using MySQL but you really should tag the question explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to wrap the query inside `mysql_result()` or `mysql_fetch_array()`:

```
<?php
  $query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM memberData WHERE mBirthday BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK" );
  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $retrieveBirthdays = $rows;
  }
  foreach ($retrieveBirthdays as $retrieveBirthday) {
    echo $retrieveBirthday;
  }
?>
```

Comment: this works! but how would i display the fields into a table, because at the moment all the details for the member are in one line and difficult to read, or better yet.. how would i just echo Firstname, Surname has a birthday soon! then the date.

Comment: `how would i display the fields into a table` - HTML

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the birthday is stored as a full date for some year in the past.  The problem then gets more complicated because of birthdays that might wrap the year.

So, one method is to move the birthday into the current year and then do the comparison.  You can do this by replacing the year:

```
SELECT *
FROM memberData md
WHERE date(concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(mBirthday), day(mBirthDay)))
          BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
```

This uses the logic from your query, which is one week before to one week after the current date.  You would tweak the logic if you only want birthdays coming up in the next week.

Comment: I'm not getting anything from this, no error either

Comment: @ili . . . That's what happens when one uses `str_to_date()` without a format.  Oops.  `date()` should be able to figure out the date format.

Comment: How should i echo it? because it's still showing nothing

Comment: Does a birthdate fall within the specified period?

Comment: @WorkSmarterI have 25th feb, 2nd of march and 4th of march so it ought to work

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query as:

```
SELECT * FROM memberData WHERE WEEK(mBirthday) = WEEK(NOW())
```